# No output from Checkstyle in ANT

Tags: ant, checkstyle

I am not using an automated build tool.  Just Checkstyle 5.5 and ANT 1.8.
I am trying to have Checkstyle run in my ANT script.  The ANT script executes without error, but doesn't seem to call Checkstyle.  I get no output except ANT reports BUILD SUCCESSFUL.
Here is my ant script:

```
<project name="ccu" xmlns:cs="antlib:com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle">

<target name="checkstyle" description="Generates a report of code convention violations.">

<cs:checkstyle config="custom_check.xml">
<fileset dir="src" casesensitive="yes">
  <include name="**/*.java"/>
</fileset>
<!--
  <fileset dir="src" includes="**\*.java"/>
-->
</cs:checkstyle>

</target>
</project>
```

what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

It was a classpath problem.  For some reason I needed to direct the ANT classpath to the class files not the jar.
My final script looks like this:

```
<project name="ccu" xmlns:cs="antlib:com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle">

<taskdef resource="checkstyletask.properties">
        <classpath>  
                <pathelement location="C:\myClasses\bin"/>
                <pathelement location="C:\checkstyle-5.5\checkstyle-5.5-all.jar"/>
        </classpath>
</taskdef>

<checkstyle config="custom_check.xml">

  <fileset dir="src" includes="**/*.java"/>

</checkstyle>

</project>
```