# Checkstyle Issues in Build

Tags: xml, ant, build, path, checkstyle

I am having trouble with adding checkstyle to my build file. I have been attempting to follow the tutorial at http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/anttask.html as well as look at examples of code that use checkstyles and find solutions to my problem (such as [No output from Checkstyle in ANT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638019/no-output-from-checkstyle-in-ant)), but when I ant build the file (terminal command ant compile jar run), nothing along the lines of checkstyle seems to happen. I think I've inserted the packages in the correct directories. Here is part of my buildfile code:

```
<property name="checkstyle.dir" location="home/lakers/NoteTaker/analysis/bin/checkstyle-5.6" />
```

...

```
   <target name="checkstyle">
    <taskdef resource="checkstyletask.properties">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="home/lakers/NoteTaker/analysis/bin"/>
        <pathelement location ="home/lakers/NoteTaker/analysis/bin/checkstyle-5.6/checkstyle-5.6-all.jar"/>
    </classpath>
    </taskdef>

    <echo>Starting checkstyle</echo>
    <checkstyle config="sun_checks.xml" failOnViolation="false">
        <fileset dir="src" includes="**/*.java"/>
        <fileset dir="NoteTaker/NoteTaker/src/notetaker" includes="**/*.java"/>
        <formatter type="plain"/>
    </checkstyle>
    <echo>Checkstyle finished</echo>
</target>
```

If anything I said is unclear, please let me know and I will try to clarify. Your help is greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the following files are present:

1. `checkstyle-5.6-all.jar`   **-- in --**  `home/lakers/NoteTaker/analysis/bin/checkstyle-5.6/checkstyle-5.6-all.jar`,
2. `sun_checks.xml`  **-- in your --** `base directory`

maybe you missed the proper directory for sun_checks.xml.

I have made one build file and its working properly.

The directory structure is :

```
project
|--------src
|         |------packages/*.java files
|
|--------files
          |------checkstyle-all-5.6.jar
          |------sun_checks.xml
```

I have copied *checkstyle-all-5.6.jar* and *sun_checks.xml* to this project directory.

My build.xml looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="XYZ" basedir="." default="job">

    <taskdef resource="checkstyletask.properties" classpath="${basedir}/files/checkstyle-5.6-all.jar" />

    <target name="job">
        <checkstyle config="files/sun_checks.xml"
            failureProperty="checkstyle.failure" failOnViolation="false">
            <fileset dir="src" includes="**/*.java" />
            <formatter type="plain" />
        </checkstyle>

        <echo>Job is Done</echo>
    </target>

</project>
```

I have run this build file and its giving the violations correctly.